# Issue implementing proper collision in XNA Game Studio 4.0

Tags: c#, collision-detection, xna-4.0

I am building a game in XNA 4.0, where a player moves about a 2 dimensional (vertical perspective) map consisting of blocks. My issue is creating proper collision between the payer and the blocks (basic game physics.) The player moves more than 1px per frame, so .Intersects() just isn't enough, I need physical contact collision that can function in a gravity environment. The current version I currently have is a piece of garbage and only works occasionally.

Basically, all that the collision system needs to do is stop gravity when the player lands on a block, and provide some decent physics when the player hits blocks (movement in that direction ceases). The idea behind my current solution is to move the next Position around until it finds a clear spot, but it doesn't work well. I have an idea why, just have no idea how to do it properly.

I know there must be a better way to do this. What would be the best method of making this kind of collision work properly?

Thanks

Comment: I know it's useful doing the "nitty gritty" yourself, but there are teams of dedicated developers that did this hard work for you. Have you thought about integrating this game with a physics engine, like [Farseer?](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/) Also, you may get a better response over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ryrich used this: [link](http://go.colorize.net/xna/2d_collision_response_xna/) and it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job perfectly, you just need to sort through a few syntax errors. http://go.colorize.net/xna/2d_collision_response_xna/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.